# algebra, solving equations with variables on both sides

Tags: arithmetic

Janine has job offers at two companies. One company offers a starting salary of $\$28,000$ with a raise of $\$3000$ each year. The other company offers a starting salary of $\$36,000$ with a raise of $\$2000$ each year. After how many years would Janine's salary be the same with both companies?

Comment: Say after $x$ years the salaries be the same with both companies, so you should solve the equation $$28+3x=36+2x$$ for $x$.

Answer (score 0):

user1772257's approach is quite general, but with these numbers it can be quite easy.  How far behind does one company start?  How much do you make up per year?  How many years will that take?